# Is there a way in Java to build custom types based on java.lang base Types (e.g. String)?

Tags: java, inheritance, custom-type

is there a way in Java to create a custom class based on a primitive Java base class to give the derived class a semantic?

Example: I want to create a `LinkedHashMap<LastName, Age> ages` where `LastName` is a custom type of `String` and `Age` a custom type derived from `Integer`. I just tried to create my own class

```
public class LastName extends String {
    //(no code in here, LastName has the same functionality as String)
}
```

but this is not possible. Is there another way to achieve what I want?

Comment: (Answers to this question should probably `@Override` `hashCode`, `equals`, probably `toString` and, if they're posh, `compareTo`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you probably want is type-aliases. Java does not support this.

The best way would be to create a wrapper class, something like this:

```
class LastName{
    private String value;
}
```

Another way is to name your variables correctly, eg don't do:

```
String string = "Smith";
```

But rather do:

```
String lastName = "Smith";
```

or just document your code with comments and javadoc.

---

> Sidenote: If you still want to use type aliases you may want to use the [Kotlin programming language](https://kotlinlang.org/) which *can* compile to java-code (and more).

Comment: The proper naming I do from habit. I like the class LastName {...} approach, but still it feels a bit clumsy as one has to access value with setters and getters, that's why I don't accept it as solution to my problem (yet). Thanks anyhow

Comment: @WolfiG The best way would be a combination of the second and third suggestion. Name everything as clear as possible and document what may be unclear. In my opinion: using class names as documentation is just bad design and introduces another level of complexity

Answer (score 2):

**NO**

Those classes are final.

Usual way to deal with it is to create wrapper class.

For example:

```
public class LastName {
    private final String value;
    public LastName(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String get() { return value; } 
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate the creation of a wrapper class a bit more?

Comment: @WolfiG It's just the same as Lino has given you. `LastName` is a wrapper class because it wraps the `String`.

Comment: @WolfiG I added example.

Comment: Ok, as I said to Lino, a bit clumsy, but it seems this is the most efficient way... Thanka

Comment: Maybe make the class `final` to? And replace `get()` with `toString()`, to allow implicit conversion ;)

Answer (score 0):

A `String` implements a `CharSequence` interface, just like `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` class. You can follow the same process.

```
public final class LastName implements CharSequence {

...

}
```

Comment: `String` has a lot more methods than `CharSequence`.

Comment: Even in the JDK, most method parameters ask for Strings, not CharSequences. CharSequence is therefore usually not a suitable replacement for String.

Comment: You're missing the point. The main contract of `String` is from `CharSequence` so if you accept a `CharSequence` you can essentially accept a `String`. The rest of the methods is only specific to String but it doesn't break the contract. `String` is an immutable object, while `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer` are "mutable" strings.

Comment: @Michael you can reference a `CharSequence` to accept either a `CharSequence`, which essentially means that a `String` is acceptable.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Suppose I want to get a string out of my map - because most methods **only** accept strings, for better or worse - I then need to call `toString` on it every time I need to do so. It's inefficient. You're proposing to implement an entire interface (almost certainly in a worse way than the JDK authors have done) just to get a type alias.

Comment: JDK implicitly calls toString when you append an Object to a String. The OP wanted to create a `LastName` object with the same characteristics as a `String`. The only contract a `String` has is `CharSequence`. Since one cannot extend a `String`, the OP can implement the `CharSequence` interface.